# Spring boot service start up error java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: INSTANCE

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-data, spring-bean, spring-data-cassandra

Once the spring boot application is upgraded to spring-data-cassandra:1.5.0.M1 seeing the below error. the service is not starting.

Stack Trace:

```
  org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'FCMMessageHistoryServiceImpl': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'fCMMessageHistoryDAO'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'FCMMessageHistoryDAOImpl': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'session'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'session' defined in com.neighbourspoon.services.gateway.main.GatewayServiceApplication: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.data.cassandra.config.CassandraSessionFactoryBean]: Factory method 'session' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'converter' defined in com.neighbourspoon.services.gateway.main.GatewayServiceApplication: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.data.cassandra.convert.CassandraConverter]: Factory method 'converter' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'mappingContext' defined in com.neighbourspoon.services.gateway.main.GatewayServiceApplication: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.data.cassandra.mapping.CassandraMappingContext]: Factory method 'mappingContext' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: INSTANCE
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:569) ~[spring-beans-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:88) ~[spring-beans-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:349) ~[spring-beans-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1219) ~[spring-beans-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:543) ~[spring-beans-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482) ~[spring-beans-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306) ~[spring-beans-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230) ~[spring-beans-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302) ~[spring-beans-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197) ~[spring-beans-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:751) ~[spring-beans-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:861) ~[spring-context-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:541) ~[spring-context-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:122) ~[spring-boot-1.4.1.RELEASE.jar:1.4.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:761) [spring-boot-1.4.1.RELEASE.jar:1.4.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:371) [spring-boot-1.4.1.RELEASE.jar:1.4.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:315) [spring-boot-1.4.1.RELEASE.jar:1.4.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1186) [spring-boot-1.4.1.RELEASE.jar:1.4.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1175) [spring-boot-1.4.1.RELEASE.jar:1.4.1.RELEASE]
    at com.neighbourspoon.services.gateway.main.GatewayServiceApplication.main(GatewayServiceApplication.java:32) [bin/:na]
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'FCMMessageHistoryDAOImpl': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'session'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'session' defined in com.neighbourspoon.services.gateway.main.GatewayServiceApplication: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.data.cassandra.config.CassandraSessionFactoryBean]: Factory method 'session' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'converter' defined in com.neighbourspoon.services.gateway.main.GatewayServiceApplication: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.data.cassandra.convert.CassandraConverter]: Factory method 'converter' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'mappingContext' defined in com.neighbourspoon.services.gateway.main.GatewayServiceApplication: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.data.cassandra.mapping.CassandraMappingContext]: Factory method 'mappingContext' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: INSTANCE
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:569) ~[spring-beans-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:88) ~[spring-beans-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:349) ~[spring-beans-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1219) ~[spring-beans-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:543) ~[spring-beans-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482) ~[spring-beans-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306) ~[spring-beans-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230) ~[spring-beans-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302) ~[spring-beans-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202) ~[spring-beans-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:207) ~[spring-beans-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1128) ~[spring-beans-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1056) ~[spring-beans-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:566) ~[spring-beans-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
    ... 19 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'session' defined in com.neighbourspoon.services.gateway.main.GatewayServiceApplication: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.data.cassandra.config.CassandraSessionFactoryBean]: Factory method 'session' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'converter' defined in com.neighbourspoon.services.gateway.main.GatewayServiceApplication: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.data.cassandra.convert.CassandraConverter]: Factory method 'converter' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'mappingContext' defined in com.neighbourspoon.services.gateway.main.GatewayServiceApplication: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.data.cassandra.mapping.CassandraMappingContext]: Factory method 'mappingContext' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: INSTANCE
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:599) ~[spring-beans-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1128) ~[spring-beans-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1023) ~[spring-beans-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:510) ~[spring-beans-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482) ~[spring-beans-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306) ~[spring-beans-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230) ~[spring-beans-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302) ~[spring-beans-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202) ~[spring-beans-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:207) ~[spring-beans-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1128) ~[spring-beans-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1056) ~[spring-beans-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:566) ~[spring-beans-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
    ... 32 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.data.cassandra.config.CassandraSessionFactoryBean]: Factory method 'session' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'converter' defined in com.neighbourspoon.services.gateway.main.GatewayServiceApplication: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.data.cassandra.convert.CassandraConverter]: Factory method 'converter' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'mappingContext' defined in com.neighbourspoon.services.gateway.main.GatewayServiceApplication: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.data.cassandra.mapping.CassandraMappingContext]: Factory method 'mappingContext' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: INSTANCE
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:189) ~[spring-beans-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:588) ~[spring-beans-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
    ... 44 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'converter' defined in com.neighbourspoon.services.gateway.main.GatewayServiceApplication: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.data.cassandra.convert.CassandraConverter]: Factory method 'converter' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'mappingContext' defined in com.neighbourspoon.services.gateway.main.GatewayServiceApplication: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.data.cassandra.mapping.CassandraMappingContext]: Factory method 'mappingContext' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: INSTANCE
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:599) ~[spring-beans-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1128) ~[spring-beans-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1023) ~[spring-beans-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:510) ~[spring-beans-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482) ~[spring-beans-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306) ~[spring-beans-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230) ~[spring-beans-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302) ~[spring-beans-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197) ~[spring-beans-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer$BeanMethodInterceptor.intercept(ConfigurationClassEnhancer.java:381) ~[spring-context-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
    at com.neighbourspoon.services.gateway.main.GatewayServiceApplication$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$3e757da.converter(<generated>) ~[bin/:na]
    at com.neighbourspoon.services.gateway.main.GatewayServiceApplication.session(GatewayServiceApplication.java:70) [bin/:na]
    at com.neighbourspoon.services.gateway.main.GatewayServiceApplication$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$3e757da.CGLIB$session$2(<generated>) ~[bin/:na]
    at com.neighbourspoon.services.gateway.main.GatewayServiceApplication$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$3e757da$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$ca946702.invoke(<generated>) ~[bin/:na]
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invokeSuper(MethodProxy.java:228) ~[spring-core-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer$BeanMethodInterceptor.intercept(ConfigurationClassEnhancer.java:356) ~[spring-context-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
    at com.neighbourspoon.services.gateway.main.GatewayServiceApplication$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$3e757da.session(<generated>) ~[bin/:na]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_60]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_60]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_60]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497) ~[na:1.8.0_60]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:162) ~[spring-beans-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
    ... 45 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.data.cassandra.convert.CassandraConverter]: Factory method 'converter' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'mappingContext' defined in com.neighbourspoon.services.gateway.main.GatewayServiceApplication: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.data.cassandra.mapping.CassandraMappingContext]: Factory method 'mappingContext' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: INSTANCE
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:189) ~[spring-beans-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:588) ~[spring-beans-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
    ... 66 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'mappingContext' defined in com.neighbourspoon.services.gateway.main.GatewayServiceApplication: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.data.cassandra.mapping.CassandraMappingContext]: Factory method 'mappingContext' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: INSTANCE
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:599) ~[spring-beans-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1128) ~[spring-beans-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1023) ~[spring-beans-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:510) ~[spring-beans-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482) ~[spring-beans-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306) ~[spring-beans-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230) ~[spring-beans-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302) ~[spring-beans-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197) ~[spring-beans-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer$BeanMethodInterceptor.intercept(ConfigurationClassEnhancer.java:381) ~[spring-context-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
    at com.neighbourspoon.services.gateway.main.GatewayServiceApplication$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$3e757da.mappingContext(<generated>) ~[bin/:na]
    at com.neighbourspoon.services.gateway.main.GatewayServiceApplication.converter(GatewayServiceApplication.java:61) [bin/:na]
    at com.neighbourspoon.services.gateway.main.GatewayServiceApplication$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$3e757da.CGLIB$converter$4(<generated>) ~[bin/:na]
    at com.neighbourspoon.services.gateway.main.GatewayServiceApplication$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$3e757da$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$ca946702.invoke(<generated>) ~[bin/:na]
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invokeSuper(MethodProxy.java:228) ~[spring-core-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer$BeanMethodInterceptor.intercept(ConfigurationClassEnhancer.java:356) ~[spring-context-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
    at com.neighbourspoon.services.gateway.main.GatewayServiceApplication$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$3e757da.converter(<generated>) ~[bin/:na]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_60]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_60]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_60]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497) ~[na:1.8.0_60]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:162) ~[spring-beans-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
    ... 67 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.data.cassandra.mapping.CassandraMappingContext]: Factory method 'mappingContext' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: INSTANCE
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:189) ~[spring-beans-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:588) ~[spring-beans-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
    ... 88 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: INSTANCE
    at org.springframework.data.cassandra.convert.CassandraConverters.getConvertersToRegister(CassandraConverters.java:61) ~[spring-data-cassandra-1.5.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.cassandra.convert.CustomConversions.<init>(CustomConversions.java:100) ~[spring-data-cassandra-1.5.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.cassandra.mapping.BasicCassandraMappingContext.<init>(BasicCassandraMappingContext.java:86) ~[spring-data-cassandra-1.5.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar:na]
    at com.neighbourspoon.services.gateway.main.GatewayServiceApplication.mappingContext(GatewayServiceApplication.java:56) [bin/:na]
    at com.neighbourspoon.services.gateway.main.GatewayServiceApplication$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$3e757da.CGLIB$mappingContext$3(<generated>) ~[bin/:na]
    at com.neighbourspoon.services.gateway.main.GatewayServiceApplication$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$3e757da$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$ca946702.invoke(<generated>) ~[bin/:na]
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invokeSuper(MethodProxy.java:228) ~[spring-core-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer$BeanMethodInterceptor.intercept(ConfigurationClassEnhancer.java:356) ~[spring-context-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
    at com.neighbourspoon.services.gateway.main.GatewayServiceApplication$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$3e757da.mappingContext(<generated>) ~[bin/:na]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_60]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_60]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_60]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497) ~[na:1.8.0_60]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:162) ~[spring-beans-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
    ... 89 common frames omitted
```

build.gradle file content

Possibly a version mismatch is causing the issue.

```
buildscript {
    ext {
        springBootVersion = '1.4.1.RELEASE'
    }
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}
    dependencies {
        classpath("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:${springBootVersion}") 
    }
}

apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'eclipse'
apply plugin: 'spring-boot' 

jar {
    baseName = 'gateway-service'
    version = '0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'
}
sourceCompatibility = 1.8
targetCompatibility = 1.8

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
             maven { url "https://repo.spring.io/snapshot" }
        maven { url "https://repo.spring.io/milestone" }
}

dependencies {
         compile 'org.springframework.data:spring-data-cassandra:1.5.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT'
    compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-jersey')
    compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web') {
        'exclude module: “spring-boot-starter-tomcat'
    }
    compile 'org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-webapp:9.+'
    compile 'org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-jsp:9.+'
    compile 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-parent:1.4.1.RELEASE'
    compile 'org.springframework.data:spring-data-commons:1.12.4.RELEASE'
    compile("io.springfox:springfox-swagger2:2.0.2")
    compile("io.springfox:springfox-swagger-ui:2.0.2")
    compile('net.logstash.logback:logstash-logback-encoder:4.6')
    compile('com.datastax.cassandra:cassandra-driver-core:3.0.3')
    compile('com.datastax.cassandra:cassandra-driver-mapping:3.0.3')
    compile('com.datastax.cassandra:cassandra-driver-extras:3.0.3')
    compile 'org.projectlombok:lombok:1.16.8'
}

task wrapper(type: Wrapper) {
    gradleVersion = '2.9'
}
```

Comment: Why aren't you simply using the `spring-boot-starter-data-cassandra` dependency? You have a version mismatch in your dependencies, using starters prevents you from those things. The same can be said for the jetty dependency, use `spring-boot-starter-jetty` instead.

Comment: M. Deinum  I want to move a spring-data-cassandra build which is on top of apache cassandra 3.0.

Comment: You need to upgrade `spring-cql` to `1.5.0.M1` as well.

Answer (score 4):

Your got this error as RowToListConverter and RowToMapConverter should be singlenton. Add CQL dependency for Gradle:

```
 compile group: 'org.springframework.data', name: 'spring-cql', version: '1.5.0.M1'
```

for Maven

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cql</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.0.M1</version>
    </dependency>
```